# Converting unidentified format string into a date object

Tags: go, time

I have a date string in following format `Tue, 03 Mar 2019 11:23:14 UTC`.

I want to convert it into a date object so I can change its format for e.g. into `time.RFC822`.

I understand i can use `time.Parse` and `time.Format` for this but the issue is I am not sure what exactly is the format of the date that i have which i would have to specify to a parse function, its similar to `time.UnixDate` but not exactly it.

Is there a way i can convert time string in unidentified format into a date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [time package](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) constants for a list of pre-defined time layouts that are supported. The format you have is already supported as one of the standard layouts as RFC1123 format.

So you can simply use that layout to parse your timestring

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC1123, "Tue, 03 Mar 2019 11:23:14 UTC")
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```